# Kali Linux no desktop environment

Tags: kali-linux

I'm running `Kali Linux 2021.1` inside a VirtualBox VM and starting today it looks that it's not loading the desktop environment. I can authenticate but then it stays like this:

[image]

I can `ALT + CTRL + F1` to get a terminal and looking at `/var/log/messages` I can see an error related to `lightdm` --> the X display manager.

[image]

Anyone out there to provide a helpping hand so that I could solve it + learn at the same time?

Thank you

PS. the only thing that I did during the day, I have uninstalled `chardet` and `urllib3` with `apt` and installed the needed version with `pip3` since `dirsearch` was failing to execute due to version mismatch and I guess that an prior  `apt` update has messed up the versions.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use startx and xinit by going to a terminal and executing:

```
startx
```

xinit is executed automatically.
If that doesn't work, reinstall the desktop.

Edit: I don't really have a permanent solution except for reinstall or use a real machine.

(PS. I don't use Kali)

Comment: Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why the downvote, but anyway here's what worked for me:

`sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y kali-desktop-xfce` --> installs the new Kali Linux Xfce env. When asked select the :Default display manager", choose `lightdm`.

Next, run:

`update-alternatives --config x-session-manager` --> select `Xfce's` option.

More information [Kali Linux Xfce FAQ](https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/xfce-faq/#switch-desktop-environments)

Answer (score 0):

You may try using this command:

```bash
rm -Rv ~/.cache/sessions/
```

Hope it work for you guys!